# Save struct in class to NSUserDefaults using Swift

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I have a class and inside the class is a (swift) array, based on a global struct.
I want to save an array with this class to NSUserDefaults. This is my code:

```
struct mystruct {
    var start : NSDate = NSDate()
    var stop : NSDate = NSDate()
}

class MyClass : NSObject {

    var mystructs : [mystruct]

    init(mystructs : [mystruct]) {

        self.mystructs = mystructs 
        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
        //let val = mystructs.map { $0 as NSObject } //this also doesn't work
        let objctvtmrec = NSMutableArray(mystructs)  //gives error
        encoder.encodeObject(objctvtmrec)
        //first approach:
        encoder.encodeObject(mystructs) //error: [mystructs] doesn't conform to protocol 'anyobject'
    }

}

var records : [MyClass] {
    get {
        var returnValue : [MyClass]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("records") as? [MyClass]
        if returnValue == nil
        {
            returnValue = []
        }
        return returnValue!
    }
    set (newValue) {
        let val = newValue.map { $0 as AnyObject }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(val, forKey: "records")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}
```

I already subclassed to NSObject, and I know I need NSCoding. But I don't find any way to convert the struct array to an NSMuteableArray or something similar I can store. The only idea until now is to go through each entry and copy it directly to a new array or to use much or objective-c code all over the project, so i never need to convert from swift arrays to objective-c arrays. Both are things I don't want to do.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift structs are not classes**, therefore they don't conform to `AnyObject` protocol. You have to rethink your approach. Here are some suggestions:

1. Convert your `struct` to `final class` to enforce immutability

   ```
   final class MyStruct {
       let start : NSDate = NSDate()
       let stop : NSDate = NSDate()
   }

   encoder.encodeObject(mystructs)
   ```
2. Map them as an array dictionaries of type `[String: NSDate]`

   ```
   let structDicts = mystructs.map { ["start": $0.start, "stop": $0.stop] }
   encoder.encodeObject(structDicts)
   ```

Comment: `let structDicts = mystructs.map { ["start": $0.start, "stop": $0.stop] }`
-> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Answer (score 6):

`NSUserDefaults` is limited in the types it can handle: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `Bool`. Thus **no** Swift objects or structs can be saved. Anything else must be converted to an `NSData` object.

`NSUserDefaults` does not work the same way as `NSArchiver`. Since you already have added `NSCoder` to your classes your best choice might be to save and restore with `NSArchiver` to a file in the `Documents` directory..

From the Apple `NSUserDefaults` Docs:

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed [a small library](https://github.com/artemstepanenko/Dekoter) which may help. You can use it as a replacement of `NSCoding` for Swift structs.

You would need to implement a `Koting` protocol for `mystruct`:

```
struct mystruct: Koting {

    var start : NSDate = NSDate()
    var stop : NSDate = NSDate()

    // MARK: - Koting

    init?(koter: Koter) {
        guard let start: NSDate = koter.dekotObject(forKey: "start"),
              let stop: NSDate = koter.dekotObject(forKey: "stop") else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(start: start, stop: stop)
    }

    func enkot(with koter: Koter) {
        koter.enkotObject(start, forKey: "start")
        koter.enkotObject(stop, forKey: "stop")
    }
}
```

Since then you may easily convert the struct to `Data` and back:

```
let str = mystruct(start: NSDate(/*...*/), stop: NSDate(/*...*/))
guard let data = str.de_data else { return }  // potentially may be nil
let restoredStr = mystruct.de_from(data: data)   // if data is irrelevant, returns `nil`
```

Finally, this is what you do to implement `NSCoding`:

```
class MyClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var mystructs: [mystruct]

    init(mystructs: [mystruct]) {

        self.mystructs = mystructs 
        super.init()
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let datas = mystructs.flatMap { $0.de_data } else { return }
        aCoder.encode(datas, forKey: "mystructs")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let datas = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "mystructs") as? [Data],
              let mystructs = datas.flatMap { mystruct.de_from(data: $0) } else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(mystructs : mystructs)
    }
}
```

It's pretty much the same code you would write if `NSCoding` supported Swift structs.

Answer (score 0):

I use this this in my project while coding with Swift 4:

`let jsonData = """ {"variable1":1234,"variable2":"someString"}"""`

`struct MyStruct:Codable{
    var variable1 :Int
    var variable2:String
 }`

```
let whatever = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self,from:jsonData)

let encoded =try JSONEncoder().encode(whatever)

UserDefaults.standart.set(encoded, forKey:"encodedData")
```

to fetch data from UserDefaults

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "encodedData") as? Data {
    let myStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: data)
    print(myStruct)
}
```